# Ubuntu 19.10 unable to find libnm-glib, libnm-glib-vpn and libnm-util packages

Tags: apt, network-manager, openconnect

I've been trying to build [network manager](https://github.com/dlenski/network-manager-openconnect) plugin for Ubuntu 19.10 but autogen.sh keeps failing witn the following error

```
checking for LIBNM_GLIB... no
configure: error: Package requirements (NetworkManager >= 1.2.0
    libnm-util >= 1.2.0
    libnm-glib >= 1.2.0
    libnm-glib-vpn >= 1.2.0) were not met:

No package 'NetworkManager' found
No package 'libnm-util' found
No package 'libnm-glib' found
No package 'libnm-glib-vpn' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables LIBNM_GLIB_CFLAGS
and LIBNM_GLIB_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

openconnect version should be fine

```
OpenConnect version v8.02-1build1
Using GnuTLS. Features present: TPMv2, PKCS#11, RSA software token, HOTP software token, TOTP software token, Yubikey OATH, System keys, DTLS, ESP
Supported protocols: anyconnect (default), nc, gp
```

When trying to install the missing packages it seems that they have been removed/substituted

```
sudo apt install libnm-util-dev libnm-glib-dev libnm-glib-vpn-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libnm-glib-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package libnm-glib-vpn-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package libnm-util-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libnm-util-dev' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libnm-glib-dev' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libnm-glib-vpn-dev' has no installation candidate
```

Any advice on how to fix this issue would be really appreciated

Comment: network-manager-openconnect is in normal ubuntu sources (universe).

Comment: I already have this package but the one from the link adds support for the global protect vpns

Answer (score 1):

`libnm-glib`, `libnm-util` and `libnm-glib-vpn` are deprecated for years (since version 1.0) and recently completly removed from upstream NetworkManager. Slowly the are also disappearing from distributions. Instead, application should use `libnm`.

That required to port all users of the deprecated libs to `libnm` (including VPN plugins). Also this done years ago.

The openconnect repository you link to is a fork of https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/NetworkManager-openconnect . This plugin (like all Gnome VPN plugins for NM) supports the "new" libnm and optionally the deprecated libs. You would just pass a configure option to not build against the deprecated libs. The fork also has that option: `./configure --without-libnm-glib`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to rebuild NetworkManager with `--with-libnm-glib`

Comment: Tanks for your answer, can you be more explicit on how can I do that?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/4fyrp56Y